# Is it an acceptable practice to use the `#` sign in links, just to avoid styling problems?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

Let's say I want to modify [this drop down naviagtion demo](http://osvaldas.info/examples/drop-down-navigation-touch-friendly-and-responsive/).

You can see that the parent tabs named "Blog" and "Work", are linking to `?blog` and `?work`, which means that when I'll modify this demo, I can have them link to `domain.com/blog.htm` and it would work just fine.

However, **if I don't want these parents to link to anywhere** (and rather that only their child tabs would be actual links), It is impossible for me to keep this demo working properly if I would completely take off the `a href` tag from these parent tabs.

Therefore, I could have them both link to `#`, so the demo would keep working fine, and yet in case that the user click this "dummy" link, it won't send any server request as far as I understand.

The question is whether this would be an acceptable practice (having this useless `#` tag, just in order to maintain the same work flow of the navigation)?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if an element doesn't make semantic sense as a link, then it shouldn't have an `href` attribute.

The intended behavior of `href="#"` is actually to scroll to the top of the page, *not "do nothing"*.

AFAIK, the best practice for a drop-down menu is to put the drop-down's element ID into the menu item's `href` attribute (e.g., `href="#dropdown"`), so that clicking on the menu item scrolls to the correct drop-down. You can then use JS to prevent the [default link behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) of scrolling, if you wish.

It makes semantic sense to implement root menu items as links, as you're "linking" to the visible drop-down page state.

For a drop-down menu *on touch devices*, the root menu items *should* be links (to be tappable).

Comment: thanks for clearing this - I didn't know that tappable items must be links. Not sure what you mean with the ID linking. do you mean to have `<a href="#blog">` and place `id="blog"` inside that `<ul>` tag that contains all the child drop downs that are under "blog"? (in my example)

Comment: @rockyraw yup, that's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

I think by most standards it is acceptable.  Personally I don't like it, and I wouldn't use a link for anything that doesn't *link* to anything or is a control for some action.  Therefore rather than use an `<a>` for the elements, you can use a more appropriate element.  In this case I don't think you need one and you can just apply the styles to the `<li>` or use `<span>`s for additional styling if you can't get around that.

Comment: the thing about this demo is that it supports touch screen. With an Ipad for example, you'll have to click the parent, and then you'd see the children. [I've tried modifying it without the `<a>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364401/parent-menu-in-a-touch-screen-how-to-make-this-work-fiddle), and it hindered this functionality. so It's more than styling basically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onclick attribute to disable the link.

`<a href="#" onclick="return false;">Link</a>`

Comment: Interesting, I wonder though if this practice is acceptable? (maybe Google won't like it..?)

Comment: Im not 100% sure but adding rel="nofollow" may help. 

I do know that google doesn't like when people add javascriptvoid(0) to the href.

Comment: I believe embedding JS into the `onclick` attribute is against best practice, as it doesn't play well with other ways of overriding an element's 'onclick' handler.

Comment: That is the point of adding it in an inline method. It allows it to override the default onclick function and use its own.